# data sharing between views in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnumber

I want to share data ie some `NSNumber` from `SetupMatchViewController` to `SetupTeamController`

here is my code:

```
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    team.turnsInt=[f numberFromString:turnButton.currentTitle ];
    team.perTurnInt=[f numberFromString:perTurnButton.currentTitle ];
    team.breakInt=[f numberFromString:breakButton.currentTitle ];
```

But I am getting `0` value .

I am not getting the data I want.

Answer (score 0):

if type of `team.turnsInt` is `int`, then you might do it with:

```
team.turnsInt=[[f numberFromString:turnButton.currentTitle ] intValue];
```